# VS2017 Disable NPM on BUILD

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

We have an MVC app. We have just recently added Node/NPM/Angular and all that good stuff so that we can transition over to angular. However, now, every time I build or run (even if the MVC app is not the startup project), the build process runs *something* that causes npm to run. I don't know which npm command is running .. could be "install", or "build", or I have no idea. The command does not appear in the build output window. But the end result is that I get a new folder with compiled JS and CSS. This is causing me grief for 3 reasons:

1. It is more than doubling my build time.
2. It is adding the new files to my "pending changes". I have to manually undo them or delete them.
3. I did not ask for this behavior, and I cannot find how to turn it off!

I have looked at a couple of SO solutions, such as "Tools/Options/Projects" and disable the checkboxes, but that did not help. I have tried deleting (or renaming) packages.json. But all to no avail. I have temporarily removed the web project from the solution ... but of course that creates a new pending change that I still have to consciously not check in.

Can anyone point me to the "right checkbox"?? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case one of the devs actually added some XML to the csproj file. Removing it fixed the issue. It was in the "Target" elements. Hope it helps someone else out.